# What's the word to refer to someone about whom you can never make assumptions?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a word to describe Macavity, the Mystery Cat to denote that you could never assume anything about him. If you did, he was sure to prove you wrong. Can you help me by suggesting an appropriate word? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Don't you think 'Macavity' is the exact word?  If you said of someone "she is a bit of a Macavity, you know", I bet they would know exactly what you mean!

Comment: Thanks for that... I do agree with what you say. However, I'm looking for character traits to describe Macavity! So, I need a precise word to mean that you couldn't assume things about Macavity!

Comment: Jeeves was _inestimable_, but Macavity is more _unpredictable_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth except by not being there.

Comment: It's difficult to explain the fact that M was suspected of cheating at cards if he wasn't actually present at the game.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps M is impenetrable?  Purrhaps undetectable (if the pun were not a bit clumsy?

Comment: Macavity is **unfathomable**, even though cats don't like water, usually.

Comment: Oh great ... Thanks for the great inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about **unfathomable**? From M-W:

> **[unfathomable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfathomable)**: not capable of being fathomed; impossible to comprehend

If you can never assume anything about Macavity, Macavity is unfathomable. Hence, the Mystery Cat.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It's a pleasing challenge because the very notion of a character trait suggests you are trying to qualify or define them in a certain way.

I would say "enigma": in its everyday sense, this suggests a puzzling entity which seems unsolvable, impossible to be understood, prone to always surprise you.

PS In a theological context, an enigma is solvable, compared to the unsolvable "mystery/mysterium"

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read about [how to improve answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which theological context?

Comment: Thank you so much! That's perfectly put!